# How to use const in Cython

Tags: python, constants, cython

I have read in this link: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#id35 that my Cython 0.20.1 should be able to support const.

However my following code does not compile:

```
cdef const double a = 2.5
print(a)
```

During compilation it says

```
test.pyx:5:5: Assignment to const 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup1.py", line 11, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 785, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "X:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 902, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: test.pyx
```

Comment: I think `cdef enum` is how you declare  a const in cython but enum's are ints so it would not work in your case I imagine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you - solved my question!

Comment: you're welcome. I think you can use `DEF` to declare a const but it is unsigned. It would work in your case though I think.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I think it's a literal substitution just like the C preprocessor. So no matter the type.

Comment: Beware about using `DEF` as it raises deprecation warnings in Cython 3 onwards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`const` works for function arguments, but not for this construct because of how Cython compiles it to C.

```
cdef double a = 2.5
```

becomes

```
double __pyx_v_a;
/* lots of other declarations */

__pyx_v_a = 2.5;
```

and this wouldn't work with a `const` variable. In effect, you cannot use `const` in Cython in all the places were you can use it in C.

Comment: Thanks! It is really helpful to think in terms of how Cython works in C.

Comment: what about C++? we could make Cython compile to C++, right? Then can use const as we do in c++?